# how do i get text of multiselect tokenize2 control

Tags: jquery, tokenize2

How do i get Text of multiselect tokenize2 control?
i can easily get value of multi select but i dont know how to fetch text

**Plugin Link :** https://zellerda.github.io/Tokenize2/index.html

**Code:**

```
<select class="tokenize-demo" multiple>
  <option value="1">Africa</option>
  <option value="2">Americas</option>
  <option value="3">Asia</option>
  <option value="4">Europe</option>
  <option value="5">Oceania</option>
</select>
```

Jquery:

```
<script>
  $('.tokenize-demo').tokenize2();
    $('.tokenize-demo').on("tokenize:tokens:add", function (event, value) {
    console.log("Value is "+value); //here i am getting selected value like 1,2,3..etc.
    console.log("Text is "+?);//here i want text from options like Africa
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is not enough documentation but I managed to found the solution. `Text` propert is actually passed in the third parameter of event listener function. Modify your event listener as below:

```
$('.tokenize-demo').on("tokenize:tokens:add", function (event, value, text){
     console.log("Value is "+value); // To get value
     console.log("Text is "+ text); // To get text
});
```

For reference please see [`tokenize:tokens:add` event documentation](https://zellerda.github.io/Tokenize2/events.html)

Comment: If this solves your problem please don't forget to upvote and mark this solution as accepted answer.